# Make a version of make-rat that handles positive and negative arguments

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

Given the following task from [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html)

> **Exercise 2.1**
>
> Define a better version
>   of make-rat that handles both positive
>   and negative arguments. Make-rat
>   should normalize the sign so that if
>   the rational number is positive, both
>   the numerator and denominator are
>   positive, and if the rational number
>   is negative, only the numerator is
>   negative.

And these prerequisite functions:

```
(define (gcd a b) (if (= b 0) a (gcd b (remainder a b))))

(define (numer a) (car a))
(define (denom a) (cdr a))
(define (print-rat a)
  (newline)
  (display (numer a))
  (display "/")
  (display (denom a)))

(define (add-rat a b)
  (make-rat (+ (* (numer a) (denom b))
               (* (numer b) (denom a)))   
            (* (denom a) (denom b))))
(define (sub-rat a b)
  (make-rat (- (* (numer a) (denom b))
               (* (numer b) (denom a)))

            (* (denom a) (denom b))))
(define (mul-rat a b)
  (make-rat (* (numer a) (numer b))
            (* (denom a) (denom b))))
(define (div-rat a b)
  (make-rat (* (numer a) (denom b))
            (* (numer b) (denom a))))
```

I wrote this version of (make-rat ... ).  What do you think?

```
(define (make-rat n d)
  (define (sign n d) (if (> (* n d) 0) + -))
  (let* ((abs-n (abs n)) 
         (abs-d (abs d)) 
         (div (gcd abs-n abs-d)))
    (cons ((sign n d) (/ abs-n div)) 
          (/ abs-d div))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To normalize a fraction, one needs to do two things:

1. fix the signs of numerator and denominator; and
2. reduce them to their lowest terms.

Your implementation does these two things just fine.  However, there is an easier way.  To do (1), simply negate both numerator and denominator if the denominator is negative.  To do (2), divide by the greatest common divisor.

One could combine the two steps above.  Divide the numerator and denominator by the greatest common divisor with its sign fixed to be the same as the denominator's sign.  Implementation follows:

```
(define (make-rat n d)
  (let
      ((div ((if (< d 0) - +) (abs (gcd n d)))))
    (cons (/ n div) (/ d div))))
```

If `gcd` always returns a positive number (which your implementation does not), you may remove the call to `abs` above.